# Assembly set address to point to an address

Tags: assembly, linked-list, segmentation-fault, nasm, memory-address

I'm trying to build a linked list in assembly (dont ask why), the linked list has to be in a stack I built.
I'm using nasm with intel 80x86 on ubuntu
This is the linked list:

```
size_i:
struc node
  data: resb  1
  next: resb  4
endstruc
size_of_struct: equ $-size_i
```

This is the stack:

```
  create_stack:
  push  STKSZ*4
  call  malloc
  add       esp,4 ;correct the push
  mov   dword[my_stack],eax
  ret
```

Now, we read a number from the user and each byte is addressed to a different node in the list.
this is how I try to create a new list:

```
create_new_list:
  push  size_of_struct
  call  malloc ;now eax has pointer to location
  add       esp,4 ;correct the push
  mov   edx,0
  mov   dl,byte[ebx] ;dl is the data of current number (current digit)
  mov   byte[eax+data],dl ;set the data
  mov   dword[eax+next],0 ;set next to be null  
  ;BUILD THE FIRST NODE IN EAX

  push  edx
  push  ecx
  push  eax
  mov   eax,0
  mov   ecx,dword[my_stack]
  mov   dword[curr_stack_pointer],ecx
  mov   ecx,0
  mov   cl,byte[counter]
  mov   al,4
  mul   cl
  add   dword[curr_stack_pointer],eax
  ;DWORD[CURR_STACK_POINTER] HAS THE POINTER TO HEAD OF LIST
  pop   eax
  mov   ecx,dword[curr_stack_pointer]

  mov   [ecx],eax ;THIS IS THE PROBLEMATIC LINE. HERE I AM TRYING TO 
                      ;MOV THE ADDRESS INSIDE EAX TO THE LOCATION OF ECX
                      ;THIS WAY I WILL HAVE IN THE CURRENT ARRAY BLOCK THE ADDRESS
                      ;OF THE HEAD OF THE LIST. BUT IT IS NOT WORKING, I GET A 
                      ;SEGMENTATION ERROR
  pop   ecx
  pop   edx

  ret
```

How can I do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you make sure that `malloc` succeeds (i.e. check whether it returned a non-NULL pointer).

---

Also, these two lines:

```
push  STKSZ*4
push  size_of_struct
```

would be better to write as:

```
push  strict dword STKSZ*4
push  strict dword size_of_struct
```

To ensure that it actually pushes a dword and not a byte (which really would mean pushing a word).

---

Your multiplication by 4 is a bit over-complicated. It could be written as:

```
mov eax,dword [my_stack]
movzx ecx,byte [counter]
lea ecx,[eax+ecx*4]
```

---

And make sure that `counter` is within the valid range (`0 <= counter < STKSZ`) so that you don't try to read/write outside the boundaries of your "stack".

Answer (score 0):

```
push ebp
mov   ebp,dword[curr_stack_pointer]
mov   [ebp],eax
pop ebp
```

if it still fails then

```
mov   ebp,dword[curr_stack_pointer-4]
```

may get lucky

or try out

```
mov   ecx,dword[curr_stack_pointer]
mov   ebp,ecx
mov   [ebp],eax
```

ebp may not accept dword[curr_stack_pointer-4] as a direct MOV

Comment: If the last supersafe one doesn't work I'm afraid I don't have any more ideas. Sorry

Answer (score -1):

This wouldn't work in DOS

mov   [cx],ax

but this will

mov   [bp],ax

maybe there's a rule when pointing with registers

Comment: You may have to push/store ebp before using it as a pointer, then restore it to its original value with a pop or mov. Depends on your program.

Comment: -1 for bringing up real-mode addressing mode restrictions which are irrelevant to the question, and for posting multiple answers to the same question instead of editing your original answer.